# Hadoop: Unable to run MapReduce job (python)

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run a simple Map-Reduce job using Hadoop, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Mapper code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import sys

#can't really do anything in the reducer most of the time, there's no computations the reducer need to process
jsonString = ''

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    try:
        convertedData = json.loads(line)

        #Sometimes we pass in an invalid title, so need to check if medianPay is empty
        if convertedData['success'] == True:
            lowPay = str(convertedData['response']['payLow'])
            #medianPay = str(convertedData['response']['payMedian'])
            highPay = str(convertedData['response']['payHigh'])

            #adding national to identify this data as national data
            if lowPay:
                print convertedData['response']['jobTitle'] + '\t' 'lowPay:'+ lowPay
                #print convertedData['response']['jobTitle'] + '\t' 'medianPay:'+ medianPay
                print convertedData['response']['jobTitle'] + '\t' 'highPay:'+ highPay
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Reducer Code:
    #!/usr/bin/python
    from **future** import division
    import sys

```
curJobTitle = ''
lowSalary = 0;
highSalary = 0;

for line in sys.stdin:      
    line = line.strip()
    items = line.split('\t')        
    key, value = line.split('\t')   
    if key != curJobTitle:      
        if (curJobTitle != ''):
            percent_diff = ((highSalary - lowSalary)/((lowSalary + highSalary) / 2)) * 100
            print curJobTitle + ':' + str(abs(percent_diff))

        curJobTitle = key
        type, salary = value.split(':')     
        if type == 'lowPay':
            lowSalary = float(salary)
        elif type == 'highPay':
            highSalary = float(salary)
    else:
        type, salary = value.split(':')     
        if type == 'lowPay':
            lowSalary = float(salary)
        elif type == 'highPay':
            highSalary = float(salary)

if lowSalary != 0 and highSalary != 0:
    percent_diff = ((highSalary - lowSalary)/((lowSalary + highSalary) / 2)) * 100
    print curJobTitle + ':' + str(abs(percent_diff))
```

Terminal output:

```
16/05/04 17:30:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/05/04 17:30:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461978900532_0179_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/tsahn001/appcache/application_1461978900532_0179/container_e17_1461978900532_0179_01_000003/./NationalSalaryMapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

16/05/04 17:30:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461978900532_0179_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/tsahn001/appcache/application_1461978900532_0179/container_e17_1461978900532_0179_01_000002/./NationalSalaryMapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

16/05/04 17:30:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461978900532_0179_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/tsahn001/appcache/application_1461978900532_0179/container_e17_1461978900532_0179_01_000004/./NationalSalaryMapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

16/05/04 17:30:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461978900532_0179_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/tsahn001/appcache/application_1461978900532_0179/container_e17_1461978900532_0179_01_000005/./NationalSalaryMapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

16/05/04 17:30:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461978900532_0179_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/tsahn001/appcache/application_1461978900532_0179/container_e17_1461978900532_0179_01_000006/./NationalSalaryMapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more

16/05/04 17:30:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461978900532_0179_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/tsahn001/appcache/application_1461978900532_0179/container_e17_1461978900532_0179_01_000007/./NationalSalaryMapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 24 more
```

I have tested my MapReduction code locally using cat  |  | , and it seems to be functioning correctly. However, whenever I try to run the MapReduce job on Hadoop, I always get an error (above is an example. I'm running my job with:

`hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.3.4.0-3485/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-file /home/tsahn001/MapReduceCode/NationalSalaryMapper.py  -mapper 'NationalSalaryMapper.py' \
-file /home/tsahn001/MapReduceCode/NationalSalaryReducer.py   -reducer 'NationalSalaryReducer.py'  \
-input data/glassdoor_national_data -output test_national`

Is my map reduce not working because of how I'm trying to execute it? If so, how do I fix this?

Comment: `NationalSalaryMapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory`... Are you sure you can specify the parameters like you have for the mapper and reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using print statements, your mapper should be emitting key value pairs to the reducer via sys.stdout. For example, instead of:

```
print convertedData['response']['jobTitle'] + '\t' 'lowPay:'+ lowPay
```

your mapper should emit to the reducer like this:

```
emit_string = convertedData['response']['jobTitle'] + '|' 'lowPay:'+ lowPay
sys.stdout.write("{0}\t1\n".format(emit_string)
```

Notice the tab (\t) and the value of 1 in the emit. I also replaced the tab in your print statement with a pipe symbol, since the tab is what will be used by the reducer to separate the key (string) and value (count).

Answer (score 0):

according to the error you output , it indicates that you have specified the wrong path for your python script , 
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
check the path , and try again .

good luck !